# Symfony 2 calendar bundle, create datetime from string

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, calendar

I'm using https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle/ for my Symfony2 project.

I want to add an event in my calendar for example :

```
$date = new \DateTime('2014-12-16 17:00:00');
$eventEntity = new EventEntity("name of my event", $date, null, true);
$calendarEvent->addEvent($eventEntity);
```

With these lines, i can add en event, no problem.

But when i try to add avent from my database, i have problems. I have a field datetime in my entity, so i tried something like :

```
$date = new \DateTime($item->getMyDateTime());
```

This isn't working, i don't know how can i use a datetime in my database for add en event.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, it's juste :

```
$date = $item->getMyDateTime();
```